# Openshift - custom domain - SSL - Linkedin Return url

Tags: ssl, linkedin-api, openshift

I am using Openshift free package with custom domain and Linkedin API.

My openshift domain is *.rhcloud.com and the custom domain is *.com.

After a user is redirected to linkedin to authenticate with his/her linkedin account, when he/she is redirected back to my domain, a warning message to download a certification of SSL and https appeared. It says that for unknown reason the app supposed to return on *.rhcloud.com and it is redirected to *.com instead.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sending your url as *.com, and the linkedin oauth is redirecting to the https version of the *.com url for security purposes, maybe it is sending back some information with it about the users account?   You would either have to use your *.rhcloud.com url, that comes with a shared ssl certificate, or upgrade to the silver plan and have access to install a custom ssl certificate that you have purchased.  If you read through the linkedin documentation, it probably says it redirects to an https url by default.